# Vue-router components when using one data set

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using Vue.js as well as the usual setup that comes with it (vue-router etc). I'm having a problem, using one global data set (JSON output of all projects on a site), to return the data for an individual project when viewing that view. I'm confused to where I am going wrong?

My master page has this simple output:

```
<div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
import router from './routes.js';

const app = new Vue({

    router: router,
    data: data
}).$mount('#app');
```

And my routes.js file has the following:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

var routes = [

    {
        path: '/', 
        component: require('./views/Projects.vue')
    },
    {
        name: 'project', 
        path: '/:id', 
        component: require('./views/Project.vue') 
    }

]

export default new VueRouter({
    routes: routes
});
```

I have two .vue components; Projects and Project.

Projects.vue looks like the following and seems to work fine:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="project in projects">
            {{ project.title }} 
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'project', params: { id: project.id }}">View Details</router-link>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  data: function () {
    return data
   }
}
</script>
```

However, Project.vue isn't working.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ project.title }}</h1>
    <router-link to="/">Homepage</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  data: function () {
    var project;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].id == this.$route.params.id) {
        project = data[i];
        break;
      }
    }

    return {
      project: project
    }
   }
}
</script>
```

My JSON data is just set in a footer include file.

```
var data = {"projects":[{"id":1080,"title":"Hopton Yard","name":"hopton-yard","size":null,"img":{"featured":"\/Sites\/hat-projects-vuejs\/site\/assets\/files\/1080\/hat_projects_hoptonyard_exterior-001-1.jpg"}},{"id":1082,"title":"Science Museum Entrances &amp; Supporters\u2019 Centre","name":"science-museum-entrances-supporters-centre","size":null,"img":{"featured":"\/Sites\/hat-projects-vuejs\/site\/assets\/files\/1082\/hat_projects_science_museum.jpg"}},{"id":1084,"title":"Upper &amp; Lower Fosters","name":"upper-lower-fosters","size":null,"img":{"featured":"\/Sites\/hat-projects-vuejs\/site\/assets\/files\/1084\/hat_projects_upper_lower_fosters.jpg"}},{"id":1086,"title":"Jerwood Gallery","name":"jerwood-gallery","size":null,"img":{"featured":"\/Sites\/hat-projects-vuejs\/site\/assets\/files\/1086\/hat_projects_jerwood.jpg"}},{"id":1101,"title":"High House Artists\u2019 Studios","name":"high-house-artists-studios","size":null,"img":{"featured":"\/Sites\/hat-projects-vuejs\/site\/assets\/files\/1101\/hat_projects_high_house_artists_studios.jpg"}},{"id":1115,"title":"Stoke Barn","name":"stoke-barn","size":null,"img":{"featured":"\/Sites\/hat-projects-vuejs\/site\/assets\/files\/1115\/hat_projects_stoke_barn.jpg"}}]}
```

Comment: I can't see that you are passing any `data` to the Project.vue, basically It doesn't exist there.

Comment: I tried `return data` before `var project` etc but still no luck.

Comment: My point was on that JSON data are not available in any of components, because I can't see you pass them anywhere...The idea is to have data in some kind of root level, than you can pass particular data to another components via props.

Comment: I'll update with my app.js – data is set there.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say, but when you want to make something like this you should have sort of API endpoint that return single project - if you followed REST Architecture standards.
You can have look at my repo, to see proper way of doing it https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp/tree/master/public/app/themes/vuewp/app
If you have questions, feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work except for one minor mistake. Your global object, `data`, is not the object you want to iterate over. You want to iterate over `data.projects`.

```
var project;
for (var i = 0; i < data.projects.length; i++) {
  if (data.projects[i].id == this.$route.params.id) {
    project = data.projects[i];
    break;
  }
}
```